# Why do I get an empty list of friends? Facebook SDK Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

My Android Code:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            Log.e("AAAAA=onSuccess", profile.getId());
            GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequestAsyncTask = new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/me/friends",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray rawName = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                                Log.e("AAAAA=onCompleted", rawName.toString());
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
```

Why do I get an empty list of friends?

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I only have 1 each . But I get an empty list . Why is this happening? Tell me what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Applications created after **April 30th 2014** uses version 2.0+ of the Graph API, which will only return your user's friends that have you app installed. There is no way to retrieve all the friends of you user. It is against Facebook's privacy policy. [More Info](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/)

Comment: You mean , facebook SDK is not working ? .

Why use it if you can not get a list of friends

Comment: no the SDK is working as it should, I am saying the endpoint `me/friends` would only return the list of friends that use your app. Please read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/) It will resolve your doubts

Comment: YES.

`{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 1
  }
}`

But.And where these friends ?. Photo and name?

Comment: `me/taggable_friends ` returns the list of friends that may be tagged in a post, it only returns the friend's name, profile picture url, & a tagging token that may be used to tag them in posts. [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-TAGGABLE_FRIENDS)